# Invalid procedure call or argument vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use this method in Excel VBA, I need to process data and paste it in Word Template, I have done formatting in word template document, all I want is to copy table from excel to word and the change table to text and keep word formatting.

Following code is giving me an error on ConvertToText when I run this.

```
Const wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator as Integer = 3
Set objWord = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
'Clear the error between errors
Err.Clear
'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
If objWord Is Nothing Then Set objWord = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
'Handle if the Word Application is not found
If Err.Number = 429 Then
    MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
    GoTo SafeExit
End If
On Error GoTo 0

If FileOrDirExists(sPath & "\" & sTplName) Then
    Set objDoc = objWord.documents.Add(sPath & "\" & sTplName)
    objWord.Visible = True
Else
    MsgBox "Cannot find Word template, function aborted.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Function Aborted"
    GoTo SafeExit
End If

rngCopy.Copy
Set objSelection = objWord.Selection

With objSelection
    .PasteExcelTable linkedtoexcel:=False, wordformatting:=True, RTF:=False
    .Tables(1).Rows.ConvertToText _
     Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator, _
     NestedTables:=True
End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
```

The only error I get is on this line:

```
.Tables(1).Rows.ConvertToText _
     Separator:=wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator, _
     NestedTables:=True
```

If I remove this line it copies and creates table in word file but I want to remove table and convert it to text with default formatting of word template document.

**Before Removing Table:**

[image: BEFORE]

**After Removing Table:**

[image: AFTER]

It should look exactly same as before image but not in table.

Comment: How do we reproduce your error?

Comment: What is `objSelection`? Please update your question to include more relevant code so we can understand what you are doing exactly, and can reproduce your error if need be.

Comment: Sorry for that please have a look now I have copied more piece of code which explains bit more. Thanks

Comment: I presume that you run this code from Excel. Therefore Excel is the active application. I doubt that there as any selection in Word under that circumstance. So, examine your objSelection`. Quite generally speaking, using the Selection object in VBA should be avoided. Here you can see why.

Comment: Yes I am running through Excel, can you please piece of code which I can use instead of Selection object

Comment: Are you latebinding or early binding? If you are late binding then declare this at the top `Const wdSeparateByDefaultListSeparator as Integer = 3` and then try again

Comment: its working table is removed but the formatting has been changed as well. How can I keep word formatting

Comment: I want the table to be removed only and leave the text where they are but now its showing wrong tabs spaces

Comment: I am not sure I undertsand. Can you post a before and after image so that I can understand what you want?

Comment: BTW the line `objDoc.tables(1).Borders.Enable = False` will fail. because there will no table after `.Tables(1).Rows.ConvertToText`

Comment: I have edited the question and added images also I have removed this line. Please let me know how can I only remove table and show text as it is keeping before image formatting.

Comment: For that to happen, remove only the borders. Do not `.ConvertToText` as it will remove all formatting.

Comment: But it will still be in table I don't want it to be in table.

Comment: Well, in that case, after pasting the table, record a macro in word and format the pasted table as you want it and see what code do you get.